# Custom Metadata type variable for SOQL In Clause

Tags: apex, soql, query, dynamic-soql

I query a custom metadata type value and try to use it in IN clause.

- **Scenario 1: Works!**

Custom Metadata value has `AccountHandlerTest` ( not in single quotes).
[image]

```
ACustomMetaDatatype__mdt custMeta =[select id,Value__c from ACustomMetaDatatype__mdt where developername='ARecord'];

String[] ss = new String[]{custMeta.Value__c};
ApexClass[] testClasses = [SELECT Id FROM ApexClass WHERE Name in :ss];

|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[3]|Rows:1
```

- Scenario 2: Does'nt Work

Custom Metadata value has `AccountHandlerTest','CaseHandlerTest` 
[image]

```
ACustomMetaDatatype__mdt custMeta =[select id,Value__c from ACustomMetaDatatype__mdt where developername='ARecord'];

String[] ss = new String[]{custMeta.Value__c};
ApexClass[] testClasses = [SELECT Id FROM ApexClass WHERE Name in :ss];

|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[3]|Rows:0
```

I had `AccountHandlerTest','CaseHandlerTest`  format so that I get a result like - `'AccountHandlerTest','CaseHandlerTest'`, but unfortunately that is not expected.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing values in format like this AccountHandlerTest' , 'CaseHandlerTest

You can use comma separated values and then use split() function to convert it into list

like this:

```
ACustomMetaDatatype__mdt custMeta =[select id,Value__c from ACustomMetaDatatype__mdt where developername='ARecord'];

String[] ss = custMeta.Value__c.split(',');
ApexClass[] testClasses = [SELECT Id FROM ApexClass WHERE Name in :ss];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue you are facing value comes out a single string 
'AccountHandlerTest','CaseHandlerTest'

you have to split the string and push into the list and query the list

```
classes__mdt custMeta =[select id,Value__c from classes__mdt];
List<string> ss = new List<string>();
for(string s: custMeta.value__c.split(',')){
    ss.add(s);
}
ApexClass[] testClasses = [SELECT Id FROM ApexClass WHERE Name in :ss];
```

Comment: Oops didn't realize you already answered it

Comment: Thank you both. I see user entering the value as `AccountHandlerTest, CaseHandlerTest` makes more sense than `AccountHandlerTest','CaseHandlerTest`